# Creating Stripe Express Connect Account, Getting 'unsupported_content_type' when POST to endpoint for account ID

Tags: node.js, firebase, stripe-payments, backend, stripe-connect

Im having trouble sending "POST" request to stripes token endpoint at the end of creating connect express account. Currently, my application(ios) is opening the OAuth Link (which contains a redirect uri to my server(Firebase functions)) to the express account creation web page made by stripe. Once the user completes their account set up I receive the authorization code in the backend and then use the authorization code and client_secret_key to send a POST request to "https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token". I'm using XMLHttpRequest npm to send a POST request within firebase functions and setting my parameters like this

`var params = "client_secret=" + CLIENT_SECRET + "&code=" + AUTHORIZATION_CODE + "&grant_type=authorization_code"`

and my request header like this

```
  request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
```

Yet I get back this error after sending POST request
`"error": {
    "type": "invalid_request_error",
    "code": "unsupported_content_type",
    "message": "Invalid request: unsupported Content-Type text/plain;charset=UTF-8. If error persists and you need assistance, please contact support@stripe.com."
  }`

I thought I was properly setting request header content-type to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" but still getting back error as if the content-type was "Text/plain".

Here is full backend code

```
exports.CreateUsersPayoutAccount = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) =>{
  const userID = req.query.state
  const AUTHORIZATION_CODE = req.query.code

  console.log(userID)
  console.log(AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
  //console.log(req);

  var request = new XMLHttpRequest()
  request.addEventListener('load', getStripeConnectUserID)
  var params = "client_secret=" + CLIENT_SECRET + "&code=" + AUTHORIZATION_CODE + "&grant_type=authorization_code"

  //var params = JSON.stringify({client_secret : CLIENT_SECRET, code : AUTHORIZATION_CODE, grant_type : "authorization_code"})
  console.log(params);
  request.open("POST", "https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token", true)
  request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
  //request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length)
  request.send(params)


})
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated, I am somewhat new to writing backend HTTP calls.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the backend cloud function, rather than attempt to send the POST request from there, write the auth code to a spot in firebase database.
2. Back in Xcode have a listener function that executes if there's a change in that database spot. The function should then read the change (the auth code) and simply send an easy swifty POST request with Alamofire.

I understand why you made the uri direct to your specific cloud function (since its an http trigger), but isn't the point of sending a uri so that stripe can redirect the user back to a specific app page, does the user still get directed back to the app in your case???